# Drupal limit node create/update based on a number of a specific field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I hope someone will be able to help me with this issue.
I have a content type Course. Each course is associated with a specific college (taxonomy term). There is also a field Favorite for each Course.
I need to be able to limit Favorite to, let's say a total of 10, per each College.
For example, someone is editing course "Chemistry 101" and wants to pick it as a favorite course, but there are already 10 favorite courses picked for Department of Chemistry. So I need to prevent the user from doing this and let him know with an error message that they've reached the limit for this college.

I've tried to use Rules but seem to get stuck when I try to calculate how many favorites are already there for this specific college.

Can anyone help? Thank you so much!

Comment: do you have some knowledge implementing hooks with php?

Comment: You will have to add a validate function in your content form with a hook_form_alter and in it you make a query to check if there are allready 10 favorites, if there are you display an error message. You can also disable the favorite field when loading the form if you have 10 or more favorites so users do not have to wait the submit to figure out their choice is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I do have some experience with implementing hooks, but not extensive. I have hard times building a query that will return me the number of favorites for a chosen college on the content entry form